# Como mostrar datos automáticamente de un input a otro con jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

**Estimados**

Estoy tratando de pasar un valor de un input que se carga de un modal, y quiero que se muestre automáticamente en otro input.
yo he podido hacerlo con las siguientes  funciones

keyup() : Esta función solo me muestra a medida que yo escribo en el primer input , se va mostrando en otro input.

keyPress() : Esta función me muestra solo si presiono un tecla sobre el primer input para que se muestre ese valor en el otro input.

Change() : Esta función se comporta parecido a la keup().

Lo que yo hago es seleccionar un modal desde una vista y ese modal me permite seleccionar un registro y presionar un botón que cierra el modal y envía un valor al primer input de la vista y ese valor es el que yo quiero que se replique en el otro input pero de manera automática , es decir al mostrarse ese valor en el primer input , se debe mostrar en el segundo input.

Aquí las imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora el input de mas abajo es donde yo quiero que se muestre automáticamente el valor que llega al primer input.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para eso utilizo esta función, pero he utilizado keyPress() , KeyUp() , change() y no funciona como necesito.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#txt_mostrar_nombre_estacion").keypress(function () {
          var value = $(this).val();
          $("#txt_mostrar_origen_vuelos").val(value);
      });
  });
</script>
```

Por favor si me pudieran orientar para poder realizar lo que necesito se los agradecería.

Comment: Hola Simón, nos enseñas muchas imagenes, pero necesitamos ver tu cogido HTML para poder guiarte.

Comment: que version de bootstrap estas usando ?

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias hacerlo asi:

```js
function copiarValor(data){
  //agregar valor copiado
 $("#valorCopiado").val(data);
  //ocultar modal
 $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
}//copiarValor
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Consultar
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Consultar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE</td>
            <TD>DIRECCION</TD>
            <td>Accion</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cristina Paredes</td>
            <td>Av Juarez</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" onclick="copiarValor('Cristina Paredes');">
              CoPiAr VaLoR
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fernanda Ortega</td>
            <td>Av Mayor</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" onclick="copiarValor('Fernanda Ortega');">
              CoPiAr VaLoR
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<input type="text" name="valorCopiado" id="valorCopiado" class="form-control" placeholder="valor copiado">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas uso el evento **onclick** el cual llama a una funcion **JavaScript** y por los respectivos "ID" agrego el valor copiado y a su vez oculto la modal.

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Hola amigo, la verdad eso lo tengo hecho el tema es que son 2 input en la vista principal (input "Guía" e input "Vuelo", y al abrir el modal , se captura un dato y lo envía al input "Guía" de la vista principal y quiero que ese valor se copie también en el input "Vuelo", eso es básicamente lo que necesito. igual gracias amigo

Comment: Buenos días, he intentado de varias maneras pero aun no he logrado hacer los que necesito . alguien me podrían ayudar con este tema por favor.